# How do I update fields of documents in mongo db using the java to GeoJSON format?

Tags: java, javascript, mongodb, geospatial

I' ve got mongodb collection with airports and i need to prepare some Geospatial Queries.

It's a simple document from this collection:

```
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("528e8134556062edda12ffe6"),
            "id" : 6523,
            "ident" : "00A",
            "type" : "heliport",
            "name" : "Total Rf Heliport",
            "latitude_deg" : 40.07080078125,
            "longitude_deg" : -74.9336013793945,
            "elevation_ft" : 11,
            "continent" : "NA",
            "iso_country" : "US",
            "iso_region" : "US-PA",
            "municipality" : "Bensalem",
            "scheduled_service" : "no",
            "gps_code" : "00A",
            "iata_code" : "",
            "local_code" : "00A",
            "home_link" : "",
            "wikipedia_link" : "",
            "keywords" : ""
    }
```

I need to change all documents to something like that:

```
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("528e8134556062edda12ffe6"),
      "id" : 6523,
      "ident" : "00A",
      "type" : "heliport",
      "name" : "Total Rf Heliport",
      "longitude_deg" : 17.27,
      "latitude_deg" : 52.22,
      "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
          17.27,
          52.22
        ]
      },
    ...
    }
```

This is a simple javascript that should work for it:

```
    var cursor = db.airports.find()

    cursor.forEach(function(input) {
      x = input.latitude_deg;
      y = input.longitude_deg;
      id = input._id;
      db.airports.update({"_id":id},{$set:{"loc":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[y,x]}}});
    });
```

but i must create program in java which does the same and even though I try I'm not coming out of this.

If anyone can steer me somehow to solve?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english!

Comment: Where's your Java code? This will perform a lot better if you could just run the query directly on the DB server using the JavaScript you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example application I created showing how to do this with the MongoDB Inc. driver (legacy) and the [Asynchronous Java Driver](http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver/).

For the asynchronous driver I show two different methods: synchronous and asynchronous. The main driver for the asynchronous version is that for the synchronous/legacy case have to wait for each update to complete.  In the asynchronous model you can continue to get meaningful work done while the stream of document fetching and updates happen in the "background".

HTH,
Rob.

P.S. Full disclosure: I work on the Asynchronous Java Driver.

```
package geojson.sof20181050;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Phaser;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import com.allanbank.mongodb.Callback;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.Durability;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.MongoCollection;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.MongoFactory;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.StreamCallback;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.Document;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.Element;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.NumericElement;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.builder.BuilderFactory;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.builder.DocumentBuilder;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.Find;
import com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.GeoJson;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;

/**
 * ConvertToGeoJSON provides a solution to a Stack Overflow question on how to
 * conver a document containing a latitude and longitude value to contain a
 * GeoJSON formated value instead. From the Stack Overflow question: Each input
 * document looks like: <blockquote>
 * 
 * <pre>
 * <code>
 *    {
 *             "_id" : ObjectId("528e8134556062edda12ffe6"),
 *             "id" : 6523,
 *             "ident" : "00A",
 *             "type" : "heliport",
 *             "name" : "Total Rf Heliport",
 *             "latitude_deg" : 40.07080078125,
 *             "longitude_deg" : -74.9336013793945,
 *             "elevation_ft" : 11,
 *             "continent" : "NA",
 *             "iso_country" : "US",
 *             "iso_region" : "US-PA",
 *             "municipality" : "Bensalem",
 *             "scheduled_service" : "no",
 *             "gps_code" : "00A",
 *             "iata_code" : "",
 *             "local_code" : "00A",
 *             "home_link" : "",
 *             "wikipedia_link" : "",
 *             "keywords" : ""
 *     }
 * </code>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * </blockquote>
 * <p>
 * We want the resulting document to look like:<blockquote>
 * 
 * <pre>
 * <code>
 * {
 *       "_id": ObjectId("528e8134556062edda12ffe6"),
 *       "id" : 6523,
 *       "ident" : "00A",
 *       "type" : "heliport",
 *       "name" : "Total Rf Heliport",
 *       "longitude_deg" : 17.27,
 *       "latitude_deg" : 52.22,
 *       "loc" : {
 *         "type" : "Point",
 *         "coordinates" : [
 *           17.27,
 *           52.22
 *         ]
 *       },
 *     ...
 *     }
 * </code>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * </blockquote>
 * </p>
 * 
 * @see <a
 *      href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181050/how-do-i-update-fields-of-documents-in-mongo-db-using-the-java-to-geojson-format">Stack
 *      Overflow Question</a>
 */
public class ConvertToGeoJSON {
    /**
     * The handle to the MongoDB client. We assume MongoDB is running on your
     * machine on the default port of 27017.
     */
    protected final static MongoClient client;

    /** The collection we will be using. */
    protected final static MongoCollection theCollection;

    /** The URI for connecting to MongoDB. */
    protected static final String URI;

    static {
        URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
        client = MongoFactory.createClient(URI);
        theCollection = client.getDatabase("db").getCollection("collection");
    }

    /**
     * See the class Javadoc for a description of the problem..
     * 
     * @param args
     *            Command line arguments. Ignored.
     * @throws InterruptedException
     *             If waiting for the callback to complete is interrupted.
     * @throws IOException
     *             On a failure to close the client.
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
            IOException {
        try {
            // We can perform this operation two way. Synchronously and via
            // streaming. We will provide an example of both. Change these
            // variables to switch between them.
            final boolean doLegacy = false;
            final boolean doSynchronous = false;
            if (doLegacy) {
                doLegacy();
            }
            else if (doSynchronous) {
                doSynchronously();
            }
            else {
                doAsynchronously();
            }
        }
        finally {
            // Always close the client!
            client.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Performs the document updates asynchronously. This method uses a pair of
     * callbacks to perform the updates. The first receives the stream of
     * documents in the collection and prepares and sends the update for each
     * document. The second receives the results of the update and checks for
     * errors.
     * <p>
     * Neither callback performs robust error handling but could be easily
     * modified to retry operations etc.
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * The advantage of this version is that the stream of updates can be
     * handled concurrently with the iteration over the results in each batch of
     * documents in the collection. This should result in a significant
     * reduction in the wall clock time for processing the collections time.
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * We use {@link Phaser} instances to track when we are waiting for
     * asynchronous operations so the main thread knows when to terminate the
     * application.
     * </p>
     * 
     * @throws InterruptedException
     *             If waiting for the callback to complete is interrupted.
     */
    protected static void doAsynchronously() throws InterruptedException {
        // Execute the query to find all of the documents and stream
        // them to the callback. Have that callback update the document
        // asynchronously.
        final Phaser finished = new Phaser(1); // Parent.
        final AtomicLong updates = new AtomicLong(0);
        final StreamCallback<Document> streamCallback = new StreamCallback<Document>() {

            // Child Phaser for the complete stream and all updates.
            final Phaser streamFinished = new Phaser(finished, 1);

            @Override
            public void callback(final Document doc) {
                final Element id = doc.get("_id");
                final NumericElement lat = doc.get(NumericElement.class,
                        "latitude_deg");
                final NumericElement lon = doc.get(NumericElement.class,
                        "longitude_deg");

                final DocumentBuilder query = BuilderFactory.start();
                query.add(id);

                final DocumentBuilder update = BuilderFactory.start();
                update.push("$set").add(
                        "loc",
                        GeoJson.point(GeoJson.p(lon.getDoubleValue(),
                                lat.getDoubleValue())));

                final Callback<Long> updateCallback = new Callback<Long>() {

                    // Child Phaser for the update.
                    final Phaser updateFinished = new Phaser(streamFinished, 1);

                    @Override
                    public void callback(final Long result) {
                        // All done. Notify the stream.
                        updates.addAndGet(result);
                        updateFinished.arriveAndDeregister();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void exception(final Throwable thrown) {
                        System.err.printf("Update of {0} failed.\n", id);
                        thrown.printStackTrace();
                        callback(null);
                    }
                };

                theCollection.updateAsync(updateCallback, query, update,
                        Durability.ACK);
            }

            @Override
            public synchronized void done() {
                streamFinished.arriveAndDeregister();
            }

            @Override
            public void exception(final Throwable thrown) {
                thrown.printStackTrace();
                done();
            }
        };

        // Now to kick off the processing.
        theCollection.streamingFind(streamCallback, Find.ALL);

        // Need to wait for the stream and updates to finish.
        finished.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();

        System.out.printf("Updated %d documents asynchronously.%n",
                updates.get());
    }

    /**
     * Performs the document updates using the legacy driver.
     * <p>
     * The main draw back here (other than those discussed in
     * {@link #doSynchronously()}) is the difficulty creating the GeoJSON
     * documents.
     * </p>
     * 
     * @throws UnknownHostException
     *             On an invalid URI.
     */
    protected static void doLegacy() throws UnknownHostException {
        // Execute the query to find all of the documents and then
        // update them.
        final com.mongodb.MongoClient legacyClient = new com.mongodb.MongoClient(
                new MongoClientURI(URI));
        final com.mongodb.DBCollection legacyCollection = legacyClient.getDB(
                theCollection.getDatabaseName()).getCollection(
                theCollection.getName());
        try {
            int count = 0;
            for (final DBObject doc : legacyCollection.find()) {
                final Object id = doc.get("_id");
                final Number lat = (Number) doc.get("latitude_deg");
                final Number lon = (Number) doc.get("longitude_deg");

                final BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
                query.append("_id", id);

                final ArrayList<Double> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
                coordinates.add(lon.doubleValue());
                coordinates.add(lat.doubleValue());
                final BasicDBObject geojson = new BasicDBObject("type", "Point");
                geojson.append("coordinates", coordinates);
                final BasicDBObject set = new BasicDBObject("loc", geojson);
                final BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$set", set);

                legacyCollection.update(query, update, /* upsert= */false,
                /* multi= */false, WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED);

                count += 1;
            }
            System.out.printf("Updated %d documents via the legacy driver.%n",
                    count);
        }
        finally {
            // Always close the client.
            legacyClient.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Performs the document updates synchronously.
     * <p>
     * While this version is conceptually easier to implement the need to wait
     * for each update to complete before processing the next document has a
     * severe impact on the wall clock time required to complete the update all
     * but the smallest of documents.
     */
    protected static void doSynchronously() {
        // Execute the query to find all of the documents and then
        // update them.
        int count = 0;
        for (final Document doc : theCollection.find(Find.ALL)) {
            final Element id = doc.get("_id");
            final NumericElement lat = doc.get(NumericElement.class,
                    "latitude_deg");
            final NumericElement lon = doc.get(NumericElement.class,
                    "longitude_deg");

            final DocumentBuilder query = BuilderFactory.start();
            query.add(id);

            final DocumentBuilder update = BuilderFactory.start();
            update.push("$set").add(
                    "loc",
                    GeoJson.point(GeoJson.p(lon.getDoubleValue(),
                            lat.getDoubleValue())));

            theCollection.update(query, update, Durability.ACK);

            count += 1;
        }
        System.out.printf("Updated %d documents synchronously.%n",
                count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.
I used legacy driver method and a little change code couse i've got:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Numberat
```

Code look like this:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
    import com.mongodb.DB;
    import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
    import com.mongodb.DBObject;
    import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
    import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;


    public class Geo {

        public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
                IOException {

            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);

            DB db = mongoClient.getDB("test");

            DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("airports2");


            try {
                int count = 0;
                for (final DBObject doc : coll.find()) {
                    final Object id = doc.get("_id");
                    final Number lat = Double.parseDouble(doc.get("latitude_deg").toString());
                    final Number lon = Double.parseDouble(doc.get("longitude_deg").toString());

                    final BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
                    query.append("_id", id);

                    final ArrayList coordinates = new ArrayList();
                    coordinates.add(lon.doubleValue());
                    coordinates.add(lat.doubleValue());
                    final BasicDBObject geojson = new BasicDBObject("type", "Point");
                    geojson.append("coordinates", coordinates);
                    final BasicDBObject set = new BasicDBObject("loc", geojson);
                    final BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$set", set);

                    coll.update(query, update, /* upsert= */false,
                    /* multi= */false, WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED);

                    count += 1;
                }
                System.out.printf("Updated %d documents via the legacy driver.%n",
                        count);
            }
            finally {
                // Always close the client.
                mongoClient.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

and it works but the number of updated documents it's note the same as db.airports.count() what worries me.

I am using collection [airports](http://www.ourairports.com/data/airports.csv).